# How to change terminal to include <time of day> and <pwd>

Tags: shell, pwd

How can i make my shell prompt read:

```
<pwd>$                 <time of day>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like this in your .bashrc or .bash_profile (changed from yours, as I wasn't sure how that would make sense!)

```
export PS1="\t \w $ "
```

Personally, I use:

```
export PS1="\t@\d  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────\n│ \w \n└─> "
```

That might give you a hand getting things to look right.

Once you've added it to your .bashrc file, remember to run `source ~/.bashrc` to make it work.

Comment: Rich - very cool man! Now i am using it too :)

Comment: I think it's much nicer than the default!

Comment: 100%. No doubt!